# php how to do base64encode while doing preg_replace

Tags: php, base64, preg-replace, encode

I am using `preg_replace` to find `BBCODE` and replace it with HTML code,
but while doing that, I need to `base64encode` the url, how can I do that ?

I am using `preg_replace` like this:

```
<?php
$bbcode = array('#\[url=(.+)](.+)\[/url\]#Usi');

$html = array('<a href="$1">$2</a>');

$text = preg_replace($bbcode, $html,$text);
```

How can I `base64encode` the `href` value i.e. `$1` ?

I tried doing:

```
$html = array('<a href="/url/'.base64_encode('{$1}').'/">$2</a>');
```

but its encoding the `{$1}` and not the actual link.

Comment: have you try base64_encode($1)? $html = array('<a href="/url/'.base64_encode($1).'/">$2</a>');

Comment: @WahyuKodar still not working, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) function instead of `preg_replace`:

```
<?php

$text = array('[url=www.example.com]test[/url]');
$regex = '#\[url=(.+)](.+)\[/url\]#Usi';

$result = preg_replace_callback($regex, function($matches) {
    return '<a href="/url/'.base64_encode($matches[1]).'">'.$matches[2].'</a>';
}, $text);
```

It takes a function as the second argument. This function is passed an array of matches from your regular expression and is expected to return back the whole replacement string.

Answer (score -1):

I guess you can't do it with `preg_replace`, instead, you have to use `preg_match_all` and loop in results:

```
$bbcode = array('#\[url=(.+)](.+)\[/url\]#Usi');
$html = array('<a href="$1">$2</a>');
$out = array();
$text = preg_matc_all($text, $bbcode, $out, PREG_SET_ORDER);

for ($i = 0; $i < count($out); $i++) {
   // $out[$i][0] should be the html matched fragment
   // $out[$i][1] should be your url
   // $out[$i][2] should be the anchor text

   // fills the $html replace var
   $replace = str_replace(
          array('$1','$2'), 
          array(base64_encode($out[$i][1]), $out[$i][2]), 
          $html);

   // replace the full string in your input text
   $text = str_replace($out[$i][0], $replace, $text);
}
```