# How to encode all URL from String using Preg_Replace

Tags: php, regex, encoding, href, preg-replace-callback

I want to encode all my links to `base64`, but the regex pattern is not working as intended.

This is my code:

```
$html = 'ahsgdjagshjdgasjdgajgsd gjagdjhagsjhgda sgdhjagsjdgajhgdjad<a href="http://short.awsubs.co/be9Vk">Solidfiles</a> jashd sha7st7atsdgasgda sgahsfd ahgsfafd<a href=https://link.safelinkconverter.com/review.php?id=aHR0cDovL2JfdC5seS8ySDdMajh3&c=1&user=61942 rel=nofollow>Zippyshare</a>';
$text = '@((https?://)?([-\w]+\.[-\w\.]+)+\w(:\d+)?(/([-\w/_\.]*(\?\S+)?)?)*)@';
echo $result = preg_replace_callback($text, function($matches) {
    return '<a href="'.base64_encode($matches[1]).'">'.$matches[2].'</a>';
    }, $html);
```

I've read this thread that suggests using `preg_replace_callback()` to encode the `href` value:

[php how to do base64encode while doing preg_replace](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29340600/9661872)

Comment: It is important to complete your question by stating your exact desired output.  Also, if you are trying to parse html, we like to recommend DomDocument or similar versus regex because regex is often a poorly suited tool.

Comment: What is the first group and second group _supposed_ to be? Your current code has 7 groups

Comment: @mickmackusa if im use domdocument what i know is it only print what i set in attribut, etc. but what i want is find all link and then replace it wit base64 encode/decode i dont want to remove the string. i think the best way is use regex. if u have another way let me know, so i can learn more about it. sorry for my english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to provide an "unstable solution" since regex is not reliable.  I've accommodated for single quoted, double quoted, and quote-less href attributes.  But I must urge you to use a html parser.  Your sample input is not very realistic to bother trying to write a DomDocument solution.

Unstable Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/QKgt8))  ([Pattern Demo](https://regex101.com/r/EFSIej/1))

```
$html = 'ahsgdjagshjdgasjdgajgsd gjagdjhagsjhgda sgdhjagsjdgajhgdjad<a href="http://short.awsubs.co/be9Vk">Solidfiles</a> jashd sha7st7atsdgasgda sgahsfd ahgsfafd<a href=https://link.safelinkconverter.com/review.php?id=aHR0cDovL2JfdC5seS8ySDdMajh3&c=1&user=61942 rel=nofollow>Zippyshare</a>';

echo preg_replace_callback('~href=[\'"]?([^\s\'"]+)[\'"]?(.*?)>(.*?)</a>~', function($m) {
    var_export($m);
        return "<a href=\"" . base64_encode($m[1]) . "\"{$m[2]}>{$m[3]}</a>";
    }, $html);
```

Output:

```
ahsgdjagshjdgasjdgajgsd gjagdjhagsjhgda sgdhjagsjdgajhgdjad<a <a href="aHR0cDovL3Nob3J0LmF3c3Vicy5jby9iZTlWaw==">Solidfiles</a> jashd sha7st7atsdgasgda sgahsfd ahgsfafd<a <a href="aHR0cHM6Ly9saW5rLnNhZmVsaW5rY29udmVydGVyLmNvbS9yZXZpZXcucGhwP2lkPWFIUjBjRG92TDJKZmRDNXNlUzh5U0RkTWFqaDMmYz0xJnVzZXI9NjE5NDI=" rel=nofollow>Zippyshare</a>
```

Comment: is that posible to make it more spesific, something link add include and exclude. for example encode link with `awsub.co` but dont encode link with `safelinkconverter.com`.

Comment: If modifying the pattern becomes too convoluted, you can leave the pattern alone and just write a `strpos()` condition on the return line on `$m[1]`.  I'm not at my computer so I can't offer more specific support.

Comment: This is the `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` pattern that I was suggesting: https://regex101.com/r/EFSIej/3

Comment: working, but i try add more link to exclude `anotherlink.com` and im modify the regex to `(?:safelinkconverter\.com|anotherlink.com)(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|` u can see the question, im update my code. it skip `safelink` but still encode `anotherlink.com`.

Comment: sorry, im rollback it

Comment: How about this update? https://regex101.com/r/EFSIej/4  I'm going away for the night.  I'll check for messages in the morning.

Comment: work, but why u seperated `.com` from domain name, how if it have diferent domain? for example `.net`, etc.

Comment: im group it like this and its work too `(?:safelinkconverter\.com|anotherlink\.com)` https://regex101.com/r/EFSIej/6 thanks for u help @mickmackusa